# CSS :not():hover selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child1</div>
    <div class="child">child2</div>
    <div class="child">child3</div>
    <div class="child">child4</div>
    <div class="special">specialChild</div>
</div>
```

When hovering over one of the `.child` elements, I want to give all of the child elements of `.parent` to get another background color. This should not happen when hovering over the `.special` element.

What I tried so far:

```
.child {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
.parent:not(.special):hover .child {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

But when hovering over the `.special` element, the background color does change (ignoring the `not()` selector)

What am I missing?

JSFIDDLE: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3QdJX/)

EDIT: jQuery may be used as a solution.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that with CSS. JQuery would be a better option.

Comment: you are missing the fact that you can't control the css rules for `.parent` when hovering over the `.special` element using CSS . so just like @Paulie_D mentioned , jQuery would be better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `child` elements into an additional `div` and apply to it a css rule, e.g:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children">
        <div class="child">child1</div>
        <div class="child">child2</div>
        <div class="child">child3</div>
        <div class="child">child4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="special">specialChild</div>
</div>

.children:hover .child {
    background: grey;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UeZNB/1/

Answer (score 8):

To create a list of items it is better to use the appropriate tags.

> *Use the `<ul>` tag together with the `<li>` tag to create unordered lists*.
>   — [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp).

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li class="child">child1</li>
    <li class="child">child2</li>
    <li class="child">child3</li>
    <li class="child">child4</li>
    <li class="special">specialChild</li>
</ul>
```

Then if you want to put the hover only on the items with the class `.child` you need to specify the class of element that is NOT the specified element for hover.

```
ul.parent li:hover:not(.special) {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QdJX/3/)

You can not use `.parent:not(.special)` because in this way you are selecting all `ul.parents` except `ul.special` (but there is no a parent with that class). The correct way would be: `.parent li:not(.special)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `not` selector on the parent element, which obviously will never have the class `special`, the correct way would be:

```
.parent:hover > div:not(.special) {
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

But because you are using classes, wouldn't be simpler just `.parent:hover .child { ... }`?

**EDIT:** maybe I misunderstood the question, probably could be asked better. However, is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JmNk6/) you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for helping, please take a look at `eugene82`'s answer to see what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the special div absolute positioning, then disable pointer events on it.

```
   .child {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .parent:hover .child {
        background-color:blue;
    }
    .special
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:1;  
        pointer-events:none;
    }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3QdJX/1/)**

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` is great! Thank you,..

Answer (score 0):

JQuery solution.

Create a new class for the hover state you want and toggle it using `toggleClass`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QdJX/2/)**

**JQuery**

```
(function($) {
    $('.child').hover(function() {
        $( ".child" ).siblings( ".child" ).toggleClass('hovered');
    });
})(jQuery);
```